# How can I convert XLSX file to Yaml in Java?

Tags: java, excel, yaml, xlsx, converters

Is there a way to parse an excel file format into a Yaml in java?

I'm using snakeYaml to handle the reading of the YAML file. I was wondering if I could use an excel sheet to add more information to the file and then, convert that excel into YAML to handle the data. Is there any API or dependency I could use to handle it, or how could I approach it?

Comment: you need read excel, and in java [POI](https://poi.apache.org/) an option.

Comment: Hi @Lei thanks for your quick response. I read that I could use Apache POI to read the excel, but can I use it also to convert the excel to YAML? Is there an option to do that?

Comment: excel - poi - java data structure(list, map, etc) - snakeYaml - yaml